# Insert a group of rows to a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, insert, rows

I have a table with a lot of rows and I want to create a new table and copy just a bunch of rows (like 30) in my new table.... 
 - the table name is account (code,code_activation,email,password) and I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-insert.html) and than try to write your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use insert command:

```
INSERT INTO AccountCopy (SELECT code,code_activation,email,password FROM account LIMIT 30);
```

You can put a WHERE clause and select those rows that you want. LIMIT n select the first n rows of a table.